# How to create/save high resolution image in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, image, dpi

I have the following problem - I have two high resolution images that are 300dpi. I want to create new image from the two high-res images. I am using the following code:

I generate the new image like this:

```
    NSString *fileName = @"imageOne.jpeg";
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imgPathWithFileName = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

   // [UIImagePNGRepresentation(finalImage) writeToFile:imgPathWithFileName atomically:YES];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageOne, 1) writeToFile:imgPathWithFileName atomically:YES];
    NSLog (@"Success!");
```

The problem is that the new image is 72dpi. Why is that, when the images that compose the new one, are 300dpi each? How to create the image with 300dpi, any ideas?